# vertically align a single-line div that's next to another of non-specified height

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Here's what I'm trying to achieve.

NOTE: This is just a single element somewhere along the webpage.
(I'm clarifying this, just in case one thinks my question concerns the webpage as a whole.)

NOTE 2: This is all pretty new to me.

[image]

In kinda light turquoise we've got the wrapper.

Inside it there's a main content div (the grey one), containing a header (top mustard), some text (black), and possibly a footer (bottom mustard).
Width of this main content div is set to approximately 65% (of the parent wrapper).
Height is not specified. It depends on the text contained. Even the header may extend to more than one line.

Next to all this there's a kinda sidebar (the red one), containing one svg (I might actually end up with a few of them)... How can I vertically center this/these?

I was thinking I might try to rearrange the whole layout to something like this:

[image]

...with an inner grey wrapper now enclosing the text and the sidebar, so I may at least avoid the "content" snooping around my header, but I still wouldn't have a clear idea as to how to proceed in order to achieve the desired result.

---

Comment: Are you open to using flex?

Comment: Are you able to use Bootstrap? if yes then I will write you an answer with the code you need

Answer (score 2):

You can use bootstrap to do that easily.

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
Top div
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-8">Left</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">Right</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
Bottom
</div>
```

If you don't want to use bootstrap you can use the `inline-block` property to align two divs in same line

```css
div{
  border: 1px solid black;
 }
.inline{
  display:inline-block;
}
.left{
  width: 60%;
}
.right{
  width: 38%;
}
```

```html
<div>top</div>
<div>
 <div class="inline left">Left</div>
 <div class="inline right">Right</div>
</div>
<div>bottom</div>
```

Comment: (and @Top-Bot) I'm not familiar with Bootstrap, unfortunately. But, I'll look into it and try out your suggestion. Thanks.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a way to align two divs in same line by using the css property if you don't want to switch to bootstrap at the moment

Comment: Will the second solution keep the `right` element vertically centered regardless of how much content you put into `left`?

Comment: No it doesn't but it will if you set the `vertical-align: middle;` property to the `inline` class. Use the `vertical-align` property to set how you want to align the text vertically.